# Why is my RGB LED Strip only lighting green?

Tags: arduino, led-strip, android

I am trying [a project by Make Magazine](http://makezine.com/projects/make-36-boards/android-arduino-led-strip-lights/) which allows me to send color values from an android phone to an Arduino and light up the strip. I am having trouble because the strip is only lighting up green and changing colors only varies the green brightness. If I unplug the green output from the Arduino, then I get very dim red's. Here is the Arduino code from the website: http://trevorshp.com/creations/android_leds.ino.

Any input as to how I can fix this? Below is the Circuit Schematic that I was following:

[image]

Comment: How is your RGB strip wired?  Are there a total of 6 wires (two for each color) or is there only 4 wires?  If there are only 4 wires, are the LEDs wired Common Anode or Common Cathode?

Comment: Please post an update with pictures of your project. It is hard to tell, but you most likely have a wiring issue if everything else is taken from the internets.

Comment: Maybe you're powering it from a green energy source.

Comment: This sounds like a wiring mistake.  At the least we need to see a diagram of how you think it's wired.

Comment: Link to schematic :
http://cdn.makezine.com/uploads/2013/07/image04.jpg

Comment: We got the schematic. Now we need a photo of your wiring.

Comment: @user3131493 the pics didn't add right. Download them, then use the picture tool on the edit screen to upload them.

Comment: Have you measured all the voltages?

Comment: @vazquez yes I did